# Websites are loading slowly in Chrome and Firefox, but are loading fine in Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, windows-10, microsoft-edge

After installing Windows 10 Pro, Firefox and Chrome take a very long time connect to websites, but Microsoft Edge connects very quickly. I tested lots of websites, such as google.com; `facebook.com` and got the same result. I can't figure out what the problem is.

I have uninstalled virus guard, but nothing changed.

Comment: This question is pretty vague in terms of details. Are the other browsers already open when you test a new site's loading speed? Have they been open for a long time? What is "a very long time", e.g. are Chrome/Firefox taking 10 seconds where Edge is taking 5? Or is it more like 60 seconds to 5 seconds? Added details will help us solve this problem faster.

Comment: In Firefox, load the page and then right click "Inspect Element". In that window, select the Network tab and then the Reload button. You should be able to see any big delays.

Comment: @TylerH the problem solved after running adware remover tool. it seems problem with malware. thank you for commenting.